# Keymando crash when press "@ / #" key

Tags: keymando

I just install the trial version on my MBP (Snow Leopard 10.6.8).

And correctly installed BridgeSupport Preview 3 before launch keymando

I change nothing, just first launch and when I press the "@ / #" key, keymando crash with this double alert error

After that, the keymando icon turns grey.

It only happens with the "@ / #" keyboard key

There is a workaround ?

[image: alert error]

Answer (score -1):

Version 1.3 was just released and should fix this issue.

http://updates.keymando.com/releases/current/Keymando.dmg

Comment: I've seen answers like this on google groups. It would be nice to know if there's a general solution to this problem. It seems that a new version is required for each missing key code.